# reading RFID codes from the card and its conversion

Tags: c#, rfid

hello I have an RFID reader as in the attachment, I have a card that I scan, it prints me the number 0007502584
while in another ## system the same card is read as 309245147896.
How can I convert the number using my reader
0007502584 on 309245147896[image]

Comment: What credential format are you using? Does it apply to both readers?

Comment: in the case of the reader that I bought the attached photo, I connect it to the USB and it works as a virtual keyboard without any permissions